# Z-index on dropdown menu item

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

ETA:  I was brought in to help with one little bit of this site. I am not the designer, so I had to ask permission to share the site and get a staging site set up. I can now provide the link....

https://staging3.childsfirststeps.com/

I have stripped all the z-index/overflow instances I had been working with so it's a relatively clean slate.

**In a nutshell, I need the Home page slider frame to overlap the nav items as per the image attached below. ON the other pages, I need the page header (title bar) to overlap the nav items. All this, while preserving the dropdown menu.**

---

A client has requested (despite all objections on our part) to do this nav design based on a static design (image) she found somewhere. I thought it was technically doable so I set out to recreate it. I managed to figure it out but ran into a snag when a dropdown menu item was added: the z-index on the dropdown item is not behaving.

I have positioned all related items and stacked the z-index as I would expect. Everything works properly except the dropdpown menu items which currently sit behind the page header.

The menu items are all transformed (rotated) and translate on hover. The page header (title bar) needs to be stacked higher than the nav to cover the bottom bits of the rotated menu items.

The HTML is of course rather convoluted as the site designer is using WordPress and Elementor so moving containers around is not possible.

I have tried every z-index and overflow setting on everything I can think of.

Is this design achievable with a dropdown menu item?

[main nav image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkJHW.png)

Comment: I think we might need some code in order to properly help you. This should be doable in the end, but it's better if we can iterate from what you've got for now !

Comment: @ArnaudV - I have updated the post with the link. Many thanks for any insight you can provide.